# Find minimum $x$ such that for all $y\geq x$, a combination of cents exists that adds upto $y$. ($p_1$ to $p_n$ denominations of cents available).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, computer-science

Given cents of value $p_1,p_2,p_3,\cdots ,p_n$. Aim is to find minimum value of $x$ such that for all $y>=x$, there exists a combination of given cents denomination that adds upto $y$.
All $p_i$'s are positive integers.

For $n=2$ and numbers of the form $k,k+1,k(k-1)$ seem to work good but can we prove if it is the minimum possible, i tried using induction but got stuck at the inductive step.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The case $n=2$ is a staple of intro number theory texts, and has been discussed often on this website. The cases $n\ge3$ are much harder, indeed, research-level. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem for starters.

Comment: Have you followed up on my comment, Sagalpreet?

Comment: Yes, @GerryMyerson. Thanks a lot for the help!